# in onStartCommand() "this" refer to the service or application context?

Tags: android

I'm doing :

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Start Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In this block (Service's method)

```
 @Override
     public int onStartCommand(){
    ...
    }
```

What confuses me is that , why can I run *`Toast`* using Service's context, shouldn't toast appear on activity itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in onStartCommand() “this” refer to the service or application context?

In Java, `this` always refers to the instance of the object in whose class' method your code is running. So, `this` in `onStartCommand()` of a `Service` will be the `Service`.

> shouldn't toast appear on activity itself?

A `Toast` does not require an activity.

Answer (score 1):

The toast requires a Context to run on. Fortunately, Service is an indirect subclass of android.content.Context. So your 'this' works fine in your use case. The same is true for Activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html